# sbt how to access base directory of project in scala code

Tags: scala, sbt

I have been given a code which was created by a vendor and seems like their engineer did a lot of hardcoding in the unit tests.
I have a unit test for a function which outputs the full absolute path of report generated as part of the code as a string.
currently the unit test/assertion that fails looks like

```
val reportPath  = obj.getReportPath()
assert(reportPath.equals("file:/Users/khalid.mahmood/ReportingModule/target/report.csv")
```

where ReportingModule is the name of the project.

The code logic is fine as for me the value of the reportPath variable comes out to be:

```
file:/Users/vikas.saxena/coding_dir/ReportingModule/target/report.csv
```

Since I have the project cloned in a subdirectory called `coding_dir` in my home directory so the logic looks fine to me.

I want to modify the assertion to ensure that the code pics up the base directory of project by itself and on googling I found that sbt has `base` as the equivalent of `project.baseDir (from maven)` from this [link](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Paths.html)

However the following code changes haven't worked out for me

```
assert(reportPath.equals(s"""$base""" + "/target/report.csv")
```

Can I get some pointers on how to get this right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ScalaTest, you can the [`ConfigMap`](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/ConfigMap.html) to do it.

First you need to tell the ScalaTest Runner to add the path to the `ConfigMap`. This can be done in your `.sbt` file like so:

```
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument(
  TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, s"-DmyParameter=${baseDirectory.value}")
```

(note that it doesn't have to be `baseDirectory.value`, many other sbt settings will work. I would suggest `target.value` for your specific use case).

In the test itself, you then need to access the value from the `ConfigMap`. The easiest way to do this is to use a Fixture Suite (such as [`FixtureAnyFunSuite`](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/funsuite/FixtureAnyFunSuite.html)) and mix in the [`ConfigMapFixture`](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/fixture/ConfigMapFixture.html) trait:

```scala
import org.scalatest.funsuite.FixtureAnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.fixture.ConfigMapFixture

class ExampleTest extends FixtureAnyFunSuite with ConfigMapFixture {
  test("example") { configMap =>
    val myParameter = configMap.getRequired[String]("myParameter")
    // actual test logic goes here
    succeed
  }
}
```

There are of course other ways to solve the problem. For instance, you can also simply get the current working directory (`cwd`) and work from there. However the downside to that is that in multi-module builds, the `cwd` will be different depending on whether the `Test / fork` setting in sbt is true or false. So to make your code robust against these sorts of eventualities, I recommend sticking with the `ConfigMap` way.

Comment: so does that mean my unit test will look something like ```assert(reportPath.equals(myParameter + "/target/report.csv")```

Comment: I cannot fathom why anybody would ask that question. In the same amount of time it took you to write this comment, you could have typed the code into an editor and seen for yourself if it works. I'd normally call you lazy, but this behaviour can't even be explained by laziness as simply trying it is actually _less_ work. So what is the point here then, wasting people's time? You'll have to show more initiative than that, or else your career as a developer is going to be a short one.

Comment: My apologies I got impulsive after seeing your reply and I simply put it out of curiosity. As you can see I accepted the answer to the question about couple of hours of trying that out and it has worked for me. I get your point and I am really sorry about the comment though as I should have removed it after trying out.

Comment: Yeah, no worries.